# Is it possible to have "hanging" message flows in BPMN collaboration diagrams?

Tags: uml, bpmn

I would like to model "open" processes in BPMN, that is, processes designed to receive messages at points in their execution, from an arbitrary entity that will be specified at a second moment. This would be best written in my opinion as a collaboration diagram with hanging message flows that have empty source or target. Is this standard BPMN? Does it make sense? Are there other ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be best done in BPMN using "black box" pools that contain unknown processes, as explained for example here:

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/bpva/tutorials/bpmn2.jsp